# How to listen for error happening inside `request.on('end',`

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code which throws an error from `concat` method:

```
request.on('end', function (chunk) {
    body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
});
```

I wanted to be notified about the error so I added a listner:

```
request.on('error', function (error) {
    var e = error;
})
```

But it's not triggered. Why? How can I listen to it using `error` event without using `try/catch`?

This is not a question about why I get the error, this is the question how to catch it using `error` event

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to catch exceptions in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/545181/how-to-catch-exceptions-in-javascript)

Comment: Or use a promise wrapper around the `request()` so any errors in processing the response in a `.then()` handler are automatically caught for you and turned into a rejected promise.  Yet another benefit of using promises (automatic try/catch wrapping).

Comment: @jfriend00, I got it, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not trigger because the event that fire `error` is internal to the `request` object and your problem is in another scope.

You could use a `try`/`catch` instead when calling `Buffer.concat`

```
request.on('end', function (chunk) {
    try {
      body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
    } catch (e) {
      // do something with "e"
    }
});
```

Comment: @Maximus Also, shouldn't it be `Buffer.concat(chunk)` instead of `body`?

Comment: thanks, but I'm interested in how I can listen to the error as part of stream errors handling using `error` event. Is it possible?

Comment: but `Buffer.concat` is not a stream error, that's your app domain specific error

Comment: so what you're saying is that, for example, fs stream when trying to read a file wraps the operation in try/catch and if it fails with exception emits  `error` event on the stream?

Comment: I am saying the opposite of that, whatever happens at the function you have on the `.on('end')` block will have no impact on stream error handling

Comment: one example of `error` being emitted is if `request` is executing and the connection with the remote server drops.

Answer (score 2):

I think that in the end, it'll boil down to something like this:

```
request.on('end', function() {
  try {
    body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
  } catch(e) {
    request.emit('error', e);
  }
});
```

You can, of course, create a wrapper for that:

```
function wrap(fn) {
  return function() {
    try {
      return fn.apply(this, arguments);
    } catch(e) {
      this.emit('error', e);
    }
  }
}

request.on('end', wrap(function() {
  body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

I at least know that this works with the `request` package - it's certainly worth testing to see if it works with the native node packages too. Let me know!

```
request
.on('end', function (chunk) {
    try {
        body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
    }
    catch(e) {
        this.emit('error', e);
    }    
})
.on('error', function (chunk) {
    console.log('failed on chunk: %s', chunk);
})
```